# Display box at this time on the side

Tags: c#, date

it is such that I am preparing my website for it to appear in the box in a best time by Danish,

this is how it should show example from today and then 2-3 days ahead. and then it must not show box more.

I've tried like this but I keep the error page who do that it will not display the date

```
    string dato = DateTime("01-02-2015");
    string datoend = DateTime("03-02-2015");
    //skal vise i beste tidspunkt..
   if(dato => datoend)
    {
          PanelMedlemskab.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
          PanelMedlemskab.Visible = false;
    }
```

The problem is that it in no way want to work with me and I have tried to look at Microsoft dateformat about how to set it up but it just will not as I will when I write the dates on the way.

Comment: What exception is being thrown?  (hint, the exception tells you *exactly* what you are doing wrong in your example)

Comment: Also, you can improve your `if` statement by simply assigning the result to the `Visible` property: `PanelMedlemskab.Visible = dato => datoend;`.

Comment: we cannot use lambda expression like this, @jesper please choose right operator >= in the condition. `PanelMedlemskab.Visible = dato >= datoend;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try initializating DateTime objects with it's `(year, month, day)` constructor:

```
DateTime dato = new DateTime(2015, 2, 1);
DateTime datoend = new DateTime(2015, 2, 3);
PanelMedlemskab.Visible = dato >= datoend;
```

Or if you are using string, provide exact format for them using [DateTime.ParseExact method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Its say to me on error : **'Wall.DateTime(String)' is a method, Which it not valid in the given context**

Comment: Thanks for help! :) I get no error now and also let's hope it works now.

Comment: I have found out it did not show my box up as I describe it to do